# Outlook VSTO C# get all MailItems headers without iterate one by one and get property

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Is there a way to get all headers of all MailItems in folder fast, without iteration and get property of each item,
I know there is folder GetTable method but it supports only first 255 chars of string, so it's not good for headers.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. What is your final goal?

Note, you can run a secondary thread in Outlook where you can use a low-level code for gathering the required information. Extended MAPI supports multiuthreading. Or you may consider using any third-party wrappers around that API (for example, Redemption). Be aware, you shouldn't use OOM from secondary threads. Outlook will raise an exception if it detects such calls. See [multi process in outlook addin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01210b35-0c39-41ae-9641-1cc5b636f2f4/multi-process-in-outlook-addin?forum=outlookdev) for more informaiton.